# element.dataset in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, dom

I need a way to list the `data-*` attributes of an element.  I would use `Object.keys(element.dataset)` but IE 9.0 doesn't have `dataset` support.  How should I do this in a way that works for IE 9.0 (and Chrome, Firefox, Safari)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`element.attributes` will give you a `NamedNodeList` with all attributes of the element.
Just check the attribute names if they start with `data-`

```
var attributes = element.attributes,
    i = attributes.length;

for (; i--; ){
    if (/^data-.*/.test(attributes[i].name)) {
        console.log(attributes[i].name);
    }
}
```

​[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Fv6MM/)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using jQuery, you can access data-* attributes through $.data() method:
http://api.jquery.com/data/

Answer (score 2):

I needed this but also needed access to the keys, so I wrote a function based on the solution given by Andreas:

```
Element.prototype.dataset_simulated = function(){
  var attributes = this.attributes;
  var simulatedDataset = {};

  for (var i = attributes.length; i--; ){
    if (/^data-.*/.test(attributes[i].name)) {
      var key = attributes[i].name.replace('data-', '');
      var value = this.getAttribute(attributes[i].name);
      simulatedDataset[key] = value;
    }
  }
  return simulatedDataset;
};
```

And to use it, instead of doing `element.dataset`, you do `element.dataset_simulated()`.

and here's [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fv6MM/31/)

### Edit:

It appears that IE<8 also has no support for `Element.prototype`, so this can simply be a function with usage like `dataset_simulated(elem)`:

```
function dataset_simulated(elem){
  var attributes = elem.attributes;
  var simulatedDataset = {};

  for (var i = attributes.length; i--; ){
    if (/^data-.*/.test(attributes[i].name)) {
      var key = attributes[i].name.replace('data-', '');
      var value = elem.getAttribute(attributes[i].name);
      simulatedDataset[key] = value;
    }
  }
  return simulatedDataset;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try the following method:

```
[dom_element].getAttribute('[your data-* attribute name]');
```