# Get variables from button css in Javascript and use them as id

Tags: javascript

Hi I need a bit of help modifying my script. What I want to do:
I have a small and easy script. It changes the class of an container so I have influence on the behaviour and looking of the container. In my scenario the buttons open a div with a music player.

My problem is that I need to declare all buttons as a script. The button ID is in my case the onclick function (see code).

So when I have 10 or twenty links I need also everytime to modify the script. My idea is to have a script wich gets feed their variables by id's and classes of containers. So I need not to modify the script file.

```
// JavaScript Document
function AudioFF() { 
    var FFplayer = document.getElementById(x);
    if (FFplayer.classList.contains("audio-hidden")) {
        FFplayer.classList.remove("audio-hidden");
        FFplayer.classList.add("audio-shown");
    } else {
        FFplayer.classList.remove("audio-shown");
        FFplayer.classList.add("audio-hidden");
        Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('audio')).forEach(function(audio) {audio.pause();});
    }
};

dbbtn.onclick = function() {
    x = "deepblue";
    AudioFF();
};

swbtn.onclick = function() {
    x = "spacewalk";
    AudioFF();
};

fbtn.onclick = function() {
    x = "forest";
    AudioFF();
};

drbtn.onclick = function() {
    x = "dreamrhythm";
    AudioFF();
};
```

My idea was to use the same class of a button as an id for the container who needs to fade in with a string. The button has e.g. the class btn_a, btn_b … etc. The containers has the id btn_a, btn_b … I wanted the script to catch the class of the button and use this classname as a variable for getElementById. The closebutton is also using the same script to close the container. Thanks for help :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will recommend to use `data` attribute instead

example like this:

```js
//register listener like this
var btns = document.querySelectorAll('[data-music]');
btns.forEach(function(elm) {
  elm.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    //your function
    console.log(this.dataset.music);
  })
})
```

```html
<!--your links-->
<div id="m1"></div>
<div id="m2"></div>
<div id="m3"></div>

<!--just add data-music attribute make it the same with your div id and all set-->
<button data-music="m1">play m1</button>
<button data-music="m2">play m2</button>
<button data-music="m3">play m3</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try that. :-)

Comment: Now I have a problem with IE 10 because it don't understand dataset

Comment: Have you fix that? Please check these out:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/12341081/5929494
or 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/7127963/5929494

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set a data tag attribute to the buttons and just read the variable from that:

```
<button id="myButton" data="variableForMyButton" />

document.getElementById(myButton).onClick = function(e){
    x = e.target.getAttribute('data')
}
```

If multiple params are required you add additional data tags:

```
<button id="myButton" data="variableForMyButton" data-action="someSweetAction" />
```

Comment: Thanks for help will try that

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, that was what I was looking for. My function is now like this:
The play button and closebutton are working.

```
<button data-music="m1">Deep Blue</button>
<div id="m1">Container Content</div>


var btns = document.querySelectorAll('[data-music]');
btns.forEach(function(elm) {
  elm.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    //function
    var FFplayer = document.getElementById((this.dataset.music));
    if (FFplayer.classList.contains("audio-hidden")) {
        FFplayer.classList.remove("audio-hidden");
        FFplayer.classList.add("audio-shown");
    } else {
        FFplayer.classList.remove("audio-shown");
        FFplayer.classList.add("audio-hidden");
        Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('audio')).forEach(function(audio) {audio.pause();});
    }
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

And here in jquery. Thanks to you all. You show me the way :-)

```
jQuery (document).ready(function($){
        var btns = $('[data-music]');
        $(btns).each(function() {
        $('[data-music]').on('click', function(e) {
            var FFplayer = $(this).data('music');
            $("#" + FFplayer).toggleClass("audio-hidden audio-shown");

    });
});
})
```